# How to add special characters to tooltip using code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am adding  a tooltip to an aspxButtonEdit in code behind. This works, but special characters like e.g. ↓ are not rendered, instead the text is rendered. I tried to set EncodeHtml (true/ false) without any effect.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in head section?

Comment: No, but setting the tooltip in asp works:  
`<dx:EditButton ToolTip="ALT + &darr;">
                    </dx:EditButton>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in aspx file

```
<asp:Button ID="btnedit" runat="server" Text="btnEdit" />
```

and this in cs file

```
btnedit.ToolTip = "↓";
```

it will work